# Disable iphone keyboard button

Tags: ios

Is there a way to disable the "," button on the iPhone keyboard, or at least prevent the user from enetering "," in my UITextField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Set up your text field's delegate, then implement the following method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)tf shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)r replacementString:(NSString *)str
{
    if (tf == theTextFieldYouWannaBehaveLikeThis) {
        if ([str isEqualToString:@","]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but now if I i delegate from user interface, all my UItextFields have this, even if only 1 must have (the others have different features)

Comment: @Alessandro why do you think the sender text field passes itself as the first parameter? You can check it for being equal to the specific text field. (See edit)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `keyboardType` property for a `UITextField`:

```
typedef enum {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).

    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

} UIKeyboardType;
```